# examples to compare tradtional math notations vs APL/J notations

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, theory, j, apl

I am reading a review to compare [Mathematica to APL/J](http://archive.vector.org.uk/trad/v224/v224-IAN/clark.htm). One question raised in the article seems very interesting to me:

> Is Mathematica really the way to go to express our creative thoughts –
>   viz back to a 17th century notation designed for parchment instead of
>   forward to a twentieth-century one designed for computers?

Can one share examples of Iverson's notation vs traditional math notation to demonstrate the edge of APL/J on expressing and solving math problems? This would be greatly helpful for new comers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about alternate mathematical notations rather than a specific programming problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that the document you linked is rather biased, since the author calls himself an "active APLer".

Answer (score 5):

One example: [Alternating series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlternatingSeries.html).

Alternating sum is very common in mathematics. But it is cumbersome to put the sign before each term:

[image: \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k a_k]

in APL and J, because of the order of operations, it is

```
-/a
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend reading Iverson's paper [Notation as a Tool of Thought](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/tot.htm), kindly provided by the J folks. It deals precisely with this issue.

In it you'll find many Math proofs derived using APL instead of the classical notation, along with accompanying commentary. Here's a redacted example, proving Gauss's formula for the arithmetic series:

```
+/⍳n    
+/⌽⍳n               ⍝ as + is associative and commutative
((+/⍳n)+(+/⌽⍳n))÷2  ⍝ as x=(x+x)÷2
(+/(⍳n)+(⌽⍳n))÷2    ⍝ as + is associative and commutative
(+/(n/n+1))÷2       ⍝ summing each respective x∊⍳n and y∊⌽⍳n, y=n+1-x → (x+y)=n+1
(n×n+1)÷2           ⍝ per definition of × (times)
```

Other articles by Iverson, Hui and friends are also illuminating. Again, the J folks provide a [notable library](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/).